# Launching csgo via steam with optirun or primusrun?

Tags: nvidia, games, steam, bumblebee

I've gotten optirun and primusrun to work with glxgears and also with launching Counter-Strike: Global Offensive(csgo) straight from the executable file:

> ~/.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global
>   Offensive/csgo_linux

but that launches the game in insecure mode so I'm unable to play on VAC (Valve anti cheat) servers.
but if I try to launch the game from steam itself it doesn't work. I've tried every launch option I've come across amongst these are the regular `optirun %command%`, `primusrun %command%`, `LD_PRELOAD="libpthread.so.0 libGL.so.1" __GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 optirun %command%`

Any other suggestions?
All answers appreciated!

Comment: Define "doesn't work": It does not start, you know for sure that it is using the intel card or you are just getting a low performance?

Comment: Doesn't work means it doesn't start at all. Steam says I'm in-game for about a second, then nothing happens.

If i don't have any launch options it works, but the nvidia card is not in use (Checked with lshw)

Comment: Try running this command in the console and see if you get any errors: `primusrun steam steam://rungameid/730` (730 is the ID for CS:GO)

Comment: That made the game launch (if i remove the launch options from steam), but it still isnt using the nvidia graphics, like it does with glxgears.

The only thing i get in the terminal i launch it from is:

`Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically`.

If it is possible i could also live with disabling the intel graphics and using only the nvidia card.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem 1 hour ago. To fix it, edit the file `.steam/steam/steamapps/common/Counter-Strike Global Offensive/csgo.sh`

Before the two lines that start with `${DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE}` you must add "primusrun" (maybe only one line is necessary, didn't tested):

```
primusrun ${DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} -x "$ARGSFILE"
```

and

```
primusrun ${DEBUGGER} "${GAMEROOT}"/${GAMEEXE} "$@"
```

Then remove the CounterStrike's launch options in steam and launch the game normally from Steam. It should launch on the GPU

Comment: This seems to work perfectly! I also added vblank_mode=0 to disable the vsync.

Thanks a lot!